# Calculating likelihood using percentages from two different samples.

Tags: statistics, percentages

I'm studying unemployment rates in different sections of a community using census data so the sample size is large and representative.

If unemployment is 12% for ethnic minorities and 9% for others can I say that those from an ethnic minority are 33% more likely to be unemployed even though the percentages come from different samples?

The difference between the two percentages is clear but is it that simple or is determining likelihood more complex when dealing with 2 separate samples.